# NUnit changing the output from Build to Tests

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017, nunit

I have a solution that uses NUnit tests.

Since installing it, I noticed an annoying thing; when building a solution, as soon as it successfully builds, the Output abruptly changes from `Build` to `Tests` and start generating output for building the tests. It's annoying because in some circumstances I want to review the warning or other messages that comes up in the `Build` output. I'd like it to stop changing the output (but not necessarily prevent the building of the tests).

Comment: With VS 2017 15.6, NUnit 3.10.1, NUnit3TestAdapter 3.10:  No - it does not do this.   Not when using Test after Build, not with Source Based Discovery, and not with Live Unit Testing.  Where, and how, do you see this?

Comment: Hmm. Earlier it was happening quite consistently; simply rebuilding would cause the console to switch as soon as the build finished building. However, I happened to upgrade my VS from 15.5.4 to 15.6.7 and now I can no longer observe the behavior. It may have been actually VS (and switching to NUnit was simply coincidental).

Comment: Yes, that could make sense.  I believe I have seen that behaviour before.